# React Native Debugger Crashes on Mac

Tags: ios, debugging, react-native

Every time I open the [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/tree/master/npm-package) it crashes on my Mac. I was following the tutorial on Lynda.com 'Create a CRM Mobile Application with React Native' Ch. 3 Video 2. I tried following the guide on the tutorial and then again using the instructions on the RNDebugger, however, every time I open the application it crashes. 
Here are the steps i took

1. Installed RNDebugger
2. Added `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());` to `const store = createStore (reducers)`
3. `REACT_DEBUGGER="rndebugger-open --open --port 8081" npm start`
4. `open "rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?port=8082"`